# Data input to MySQL Table with PHP and A For Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

So I'm having some trouble putting an array into a MySQL table. My goal is to put one element from the array into one row of the table, but that's not what happens.

```
$cnt = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++)
    {
    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO $groupname (id, name) 
        VALUES('', '".$array[$i]."')
        ", $conn1); 
    }
```

(The id is auto incrementing)

I was hoping that this would put the first element of the array in the first row of the table, the second element in the second row and so on and so forth. Instead, my table looks like this

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Array |
+----+-------+
```

I'm assuming that it's just taking the array and putting the whole thing is the first row. How do I prevent that? How would I do one element per row?

EDIT
Here is the var_dump

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "3" [4]=> string(1) "4" } }
```

For testing purposes I just put numbers 0-4 in each element of the array in ascending order

Comment: Can you var_dump `$array`? It looks like it contains arrays.

Comment: Please share a `var_dump($array);`

Comment: Moreover, it's better to group records into one `INSERT` statement: `INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL, "some"), (NULL, "other"), (and so on);`

Comment: And you should switch to PDO / mysqli with prepared statements, this is very likely vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: In addition to @jeroen, mysql_ functions are deprecated and slated to be removed. PDO or mysqli_ is preferred.

Comment: your array looks like I predicted. Change to `count($array[0])` and use `$array[0][$i]` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to point out:

Don't call out your id value to insert.

It looks like `$array[$i]` is itself an array, so make sure you are using the right value.

You should just build your insert query and insert once (see example below).

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $groupname . ' (name) VALUES ';
foreach($array as $item) {
    $query .= "('". $item['name'] . "'),"; // 'name' or whatever proper item in multidimensional array is.
}
$query = rtrim($query, ',');
mysql_query($query, $conn);
```

You really need to look into using `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` as these are deprecated.

You really should add error handling on your query (i.e. handle cases where query doesn't work and give yourself an error message.

Answer (score 0):

your code is valid. But it seems that $array is actually a multidimensional array containing 1 key at the first level. Perhaps try a `var_dump($array)`  just before the loop to see whats in it.

or try a blind for on `$array[0]` and then `$array[0][$i]` in the loop. Although blind coding is never a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you intended to do something like this:

```
VALUES('', '".$array[$i]['name']."')"
```

You can't insert an array directly into mysql, instead you have to insert each of its values.

Comment: Awesome got it thanks everyone, seems to be working now. Now I just need to look into PDO for mysqli, did realize I was using deprecated material. Thanks for the help everyone.